# How to plot an imshow or matshow in logarithmic axis, so that the grid is regular in the logarithmic axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a grid like so:

```
im = ax.matshow(value_array, origin='lower', extent=[0, xmax, 0, ymax])
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

So that the x scale is logarithmic, but the grid is regular. At the moment, the grid gets predictably stretched out (i.e it's regular in real units of x, but in the plot the pixels gets more and more compressed as you increase x). Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You need to show an example what is the problem and what is the desired figure. It is hard to comprehend what do you want to achieve from your question. What do you mean by regular grade on a logarithmic scale?

Comment: If you draw a matshow, all the pixels are the same size (in a regular grid). When you change the axis scale, since the positions of the edges stay on the same value, the grid/matshow plot gets distorted.
Actually I found a solution, I'm not using pcolormesh() to manually specify the edge locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to answer my own question since I figured out what to do.

It doesn't work with `imshow` or `matshow`, you have to use `pcolormesh` and enter the grid boundaries directly.

See link: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html